# Как изменить вывод последнего элемента wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу разобраться. Есть вывод отдельных типов записей

```
                            <?  $posts = get_posts("post_type=jobs&orderby=date&numberposts=5");
if ($posts) : ?>
               <?  foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
               <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title();?> ,</a>
               <?
endforeach;
           endif; ?>
```

Как сделать так чтобы последний элемент был без запятой и вместо него текст

```
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title();?> и другие</a>
```

Comment: у foreach можно писать as $key => $value ....  и если key равен длине массива - 1, то тогда и выводить можно другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текущий ключ элемента равен последнему ключу массива, вместо запятой пишем " и другие"

```
<?$posts = get_posts("post_type=jobs&orderby=date&numberposts=5");
if ($posts):
  $comma = ', ';
  $lKey = array_key_last($posts);
  foreach ($posts as $key => $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    if ($key == $lKey) $comma = ' и другие';?>
    <a href="<? echo get_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title();?></a><? echo $comma;?><?
  endforeach;
endif;?>
```